# How to write special character in a file with "shell echo" command?

Tags: android, shell, echo

In this case I want to write a special character(like 0x11 or 0x15 or ...) in a file with echo command. I am using this code but this code writes 0x35 string to file and cut it:

```
shell echo -ne "\0x35" | dd of=/sdcard/myFile.img bs=1 seek=12
```

Result for this code is:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2D 6E 65 20 
30 78 33 35 0A
```

but true result must be like this:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 35 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Do you have any idea for solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The command `echo` doesn't accept a `0x` prefix.  To give it hexadecimal data, you use `\xHH`.

```
shell echo -ne "\x35" | dd of=/sdcard/myFile.img bs=1 seek=12
```